# Issue with transitioning ticket status using Jenkins Jira steps plugin

Tags: jenkins, jira

I am getting below error when using transition issue status from jenkins pipeline when  using plugin

JIRA: Site - jira - Transition issue with idOrKey: TEST-12345
Error Code: 500
Error Message: {"errorMessages":["Internal server error"],"errors":{}}

Below is my code snippet in pipeline

```
node {
stage('JIRA') {
withEnv(['JIRA_SITE=jira']) {
  def issue = jiraGetIssue idOrKey: 'TEST-12345'
  def transitionInput =
    [
     transition: [
        id: '1234'
      ]
    ]
  def issue_status = issue.data.fields.status.name.toString()
  echo issue_status
  if ( issue_status == "Build Ready") {
      jiraTransitionIssue idOrKey: 'TEST-12345', input: transitionInput, site: 'jira'
      } else { echo "JIRA ticket status " }
    }
  }
```

}